# Unique number generation by combination?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have basic symbols f.e. let say S = {a .. z} (level0) represented by whole numbers C = { 1 .. n } i.e code.

There is one operation I want to support(lets call it combine i.e operation * ) the result should be a new number such as it does not repeat with any previously generated (G = {g1 ... gm}) code.

F.e. :

```
 a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

 a * b = 1 * 2 = g1
 a * c = 1 * 3 = g2
 b * a = 2 * 1 = g3
 ............  = gp
```

but i can also combine generated numbers too (higher level) f.e.

```
 a  * g67 = g_p+1
 g1 * g3 = g_p+2
 g5 * g7 = g_p+3
 ........= gm

g1 != g2 != g3 != ... != gp ... != gm
```

Every G should be unique. What we know is that every new G number is generated from other G-numbers OR G-number and a basic-level C-number,
so they in a sense are mixed hierarchy.

---

I know f.e. how to generate unique numbers when I have to use just one number instead of two. Let say C = { 1 .. 10 } then we can just generate
new number by adding 10 i.e.

```
a = 1 => a + 10 = 1 + 10 = 11 (a1)
b = 2 => b + 10 = 2 + 10 = 12 (b1)
```

then level2 would be generated by adding 10 again :

```
a1 + 10 = 11 + 10 = 21 (a2)
b1 + 10 = 12 + 10 = 22 (b2)
```

---

A possible partial solution is to hard code the number layers in the hierarchy to L to maximum 10 layers (which is not enough)

then keep counter for every layer,so the next code is :

```
 new-code = int(str(counter) + str(layer))
```

i.e. every number ending is the layer number and the counter guarantees it wont repeat.
but in addition I have to keep a MAP of (codeA, codeB) <=> (generated-code) and i have to keep counters.

hmmm... i guess i can keep the last n-digits for layer number, drawback again is i have to know the number of layers in advance, but they wont probably go above triple digits !!!

Comment: So you just want an operation $*$ such that $a*b=x*y$ for positive integers $a,b,x,y$ if and only if $a=x$ and $b=y$?

Comment: if i can understand .. i think you are correct